# Wordpress : How can i re-size/force every uploaded image width to be 460?

Tags: wordpress, image, image-resizing

How do I re-size every uploaded post image to be always 460 width by whatever corresponding height?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Settings > Media. You can set what sizes you want for different sized images.

Comment: @Oscar then you can set a CSS of image { width: 460; }

Comment: CSS will made the image look bad... is better if i can find out a way to crop/re-size/force the width to be 460 by default.

Comment: define bad.. you mean cause certain images get upscaled? well, that is simply the case. the server can't improve your images.. or do you mean the image is getting stretched..? try `height: auto;` then..

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is add an image size with 460 set as the width.

Insert the following in functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'give-size-a-name', 460, 0, true );
```

You then need to add this custom image size to the editor. I took the following from:http://kucrut.org/insert-image-with-custom-size-into-post/

```
function my_insert_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
  global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
  if ( empty($_wp_additional_image_sizes) )
    return $sizes;

  foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $id => $data ) {
    if ( !isset($sizes[$id]) )
      $sizes[$id] = ucfirst( str_replace( '-', ' ', $id ) );
  }

  return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_insert_custom_image_sizes' );
```

Comment: does zero height and crop make sense here..? i'd write `add_image_size( 'give-size-a-name', 460, 0, false );` so the images won't get cropped and the height is auto..